# jQuery UI combine a click fade and a hover fade not working together

Tags: jquery-ui, hover

I have two types of fade that are working independently of each other, but the click fade stops working as soon as the hover fade is triggered. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js">
    /*window.onload = function(){alert("welcome");}*/
</script>

<style>
body {
    text-align:center
}

#container {
    width:660px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:#CCCCCC;
    overflow:auto;
    padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}

div.mainSize {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

div.verticalBox {
    width:100px;
    height:210px;
    padding:5px;
}

div.horizBox {
    width:210px;
    height:100px;
    padding:5px;
}

div.mainSizegreen {
    background-color:#006600;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

div.mainSizered {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

div.mainSizeblue {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:5px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    /*opacity:0.2;
    filter:alpha(opacity=20);*/
}

div.navigation {
    text-align:center;
    width:500;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

a.viewBlue{
    color:#000099;
}

a.viewGreen{
    color:#006600;
}

a.viewRed{
    color:#FF0000;
}

.Opac20 {
    filter:alpha(opacity=30);  // IE
    -moz-opacity:0.3;          // Firefox
    -khtml-opacity: 0.3;       
    opacity: 0.3; 
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="navigation">
            <p><span class="viewBlue">View Blue</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="viewRed">View Red</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <span class="viewGreen">View Green</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="mainSizegreen">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizered">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizeblue">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizered">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizegreen">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizeblue">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizeblue">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizegreen">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizered">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizegreen">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizeblue">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizered">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizegreen">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizered">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizeblue">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizered">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizegreen">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizeblue">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizeblue">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizegreen">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizered">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizegreen">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizeblue">        </div>
        <div class="mainSizered">        </div>

    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){



   $("span.viewBlue").click(function(){
     if($("div.mainSizered:first").hasClass("Opac20") && $("div.mainSizegreen:first").hasClass("Opac20")){
         $("div.mainSizered").stop(true, true).toggleClass("Opac20", 1000);
         $("div.mainSizegreen").stop(true, true).toggleClass("Opac20", 1000);

     }
     else{
         $("div.mainSizered").stop(true, true).addClass("Opac20", 1000);
         $("div.mainSizegreen").stop(true, true).addClass("Opac20", 1000);
         $("div.mainSizeblue").addClass("Opac20");

         $("div.mainSizeblue").toggleClass("Opac20");
     } 
   });

   $("span.viewGreen").click(function(){
     if($("div.mainSizered:first").hasClass("Opac20") && $("div.mainSizeblue:first").hasClass("Opac20")){
         $("div.mainSizered").stop(true, true).toggleClass("Opac20", 1000);
         $("div.mainSizeblue").stop(true, true).toggleClass("Opac20", 1000);

     }
     else{
         $("div.mainSizered").stop(true, true).addClass("Opac20", 1000);
         $("div.mainSizegreen").addClass("Opac20");
         $("div.mainSizeblue").stop(true, true).addClass("Opac20", 1000);

         $("div.mainSizegreen").toggleClass("Opac20");
     }
   });

   $("span.viewRed").click(function(){
     if($("div.mainSizeblue:first").hasClass("Opac20") && $("div.mainSizegreen:first").hasClass("Opac20")){
         $("div.mainSizeblue").stop(true, true).toggleClass("Opac20", 1000);
         $("div.mainSizegreen").stop(true, true).toggleClass("Opac20", 1000);

     }
     else{
         $("div.mainSizered").addClass("Opac20");
         $("div.mainSizegreen").stop(true, true).addClass("Opac20", 1000);
         $("div.mainSizeblue").stop(true, true).addClass("Opac20", 1000);

         $("div.mainSizered").toggleClass("Opac20");
     }
   });

   // THIS IS FOR HOVERING WITH TRANSITION A DIV  
   $("div.mainSizeblue").hover(
     function(){
         $("div.mainSizeblue").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
         $("div.mainSizered").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "0.4"}, "slow");
         $("div.mainSizegreen").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "0.4"}, "slow");
     },
     function(){
         $("div.mainSizered").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
         $("div.mainSizegreen").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");

   });

   $("div.mainSizegreen").hover(
     function(){
         $("div.mainSizeblue").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "0.4"}, "slow");
         $("div.mainSizered").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "0.4"}, "slow");
         $("div.mainSizegreen").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
     },
     function(){
         $("div.mainSizered").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
         $("div.mainSizeblue").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");

   });

   $("div.mainSizered").hover(
     function(){
         $("div.mainSizeblue").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "0.4"}, "slow");
         $("div.mainSizered").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
         $("div.mainSizegreen").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "0.4"}, "slow");
     },
     function(){
         $("div.mainSizeblue").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
         $("div.mainSizegreen").stop(true, true).animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");

   });




 });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you make sure to not hover over any of the color squares, the text at the top works when you click on it. If you click "View Blue" it will fade everything but blue to 30% opacity. Click it again, it fades everything back to 100% opacity. The same happens when you hover over a colored square, but when you try to use the text again, it won't work.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're mixing using rules applied via a CSS class and setting the `style` attribute of the DOM nodes that you're shading.

Your hover code sets the `style: opacity` of the shaded blocks and the click code sets a CSS class that has `opacity` rules.

When CSS rules and `style` attributes both exist, the `style` attribute is going to have more specificity and be the one that takes effect.  Therefore once you hover over a block and have the `style` attribute set, the only way a CSS rule can override that is to use `!important`.  Making this change makes your demo work.

```
.Opac20 {
    filter:alpha(opacity=30) !important;  // IE
    -moz-opacity:0.3 !important;          // Firefox
    -khtml-opacity: 0.3 !important;       
    opacity: 0.3 !important; 
}​
```

There's a live example here - http://jsfiddle.net/Ds6MF/2/.

That being said the use of `!important` is not a good practice and should be avoided whenever possible.  In this case you should switch your application to either use CSS classes or setting the `style` attribute with an opacity value, not both.

Comment: That is great. I am extremely new to jQuery and didn't even think about mixing the css rules and the style attributes. My one question on the example you have is if you click on "View Red" it fades blue and green. When you click on "View Red" again it doesn't fade. It waits a second and then makes blue and green 100% opacity. Do you know why that is happening?

Comment: By the way, I just changed the click effect to work on the style attribute and it works flawlessly. Thank you for your guidance!